# Getting Beyond 50 Replica Set Members in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, access-control

I’m looking to build a distributed Access Control system for a microservice platform. I’m considering using Mongodb as my database technology. My system design objectives are as follows:

- **Policy Enforcement** should be distributed - If any given Policy
  Enforcement Point (PEP) experiences downtime, only the application
  that the PEP serves should be affected.
- **Policy Decisions** should be
  distributed - We don’t want the whole platform to experience downtime
  because a central Policy Decision Point (PDP) is experiencing
  downtime. We only want it to affect the application that it serves.
- **Policy Administration should be centralized** - Creating a centralized
  policy administration interface provides the ability for any system
  (including a UI) to understand what rights an individual has, and by
  establishing a common interface it allows us to more easily audit
  changes to access across a whole platform.
- **Policy Information (context) is distributed** - We don’t get to choose this if we are
  building a distributed microservice platform. We can centralize the
  retrieval of additional context by aggregating data that is needed to
  make access control decisions into a single place, but the data
  sources are still distributed.

---

I’m considering building a system like the one shown below. The idea is that Access Policies are administered by a central Policy Admin API. This API manages Policies that are persisted to a mongodb cluster with a 3 member replica set backing it. I would like other APIs in the platform to have a dedicated policy-query-api (Policy Decision Point) that is deployed along side it to make Access Control decisions pertinent to the API. The idea is that if any one of the policy-query-apis goes down, only the API that it serves will be affected.

I want changes to Policies to be governed by the Policy Admin API and I would like the changes to be replicated across each mongo instance that is used by each of the policy-query-apis.I don’t want the mongo replicas for each policy-query-api to affect a write to the primaries.

I also don’t need immediate data consistency (less than 5 sec latency), but I would like the data replication to be handled at the database layer if possible. The technology is already built to handle this and I don’t want to reinvent the wheel at the application layer if possible.

I’ve looked at the documentation on Replica Set Members and I’ve pretty thoroughly reviewed the documentation on Replica Sets in Mongo. It seems like having a Hidden Member or Delayed Member would be a good fit for my use case. Do you agree? Also, I’m concerned about the 50 member replica set limit 1. Since each one of these replicas would serve an API in my platform, if there exceeded more than 50 microservices (which is quite likely) how would I manage replication like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just so that I understand, you are asking about:

- one standalone (?? your picture suggests standalone but you are asking about 50 node RS limit) node per application, data mirrored to standalone from the master RS
- the application only queries its local standalone

MongoDB provides [read preference nearest](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) for the use case of reading data from local nodes. Importantly the nearest read preference still provides availability if your local node is unavailable - the next closest (roughly) node will be used in this case. Your proposed architecture would take the application down every time its local database node needs to be restarted for version upgrades.

You may also look into [tag sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/).

Additionally, MongoDB allows specifying priorities on nodes for election purposes. If you put all of your MongoDB nodes into the same RS, you can use priorities to have one of the 3 designated "main" servers be primaries if any of them are available.